# Can I unserialize an stored object if I added a member to the class definition?

Tags: php, class, serialization

I have a bunch of objects serialized and stored in my database.  In the class definition for those objects I added a new member.  When I unserialize the objects, will I encounter an error since the serialized objects didn't include that member?

```
class foo {
  public $alpha = NULL;
}

$myobject = new foo();
$myobject->foo = "This is my original object."

$saved_object = serialize($myobject);
db_save_myobject($saved_object);
```

After I saved it, I made a change to the foo class...

```
class foo {
  public $alpha = NULL;
  public $bravo = NULL;
}
```

Now I want to fetch from my db

```
$myobject = db_get_myobject();
```

Will $myobject now have a null bravo member?

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: _"When I unserialize the objects, will I encounter an error"_ What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple classes it will work fine.

You'll get $bravo = NULL, unless you assigned something like `$myobject->bravo = 123;` before serialization. Then it'll stay $bravo = 123.

You may run into trouble if the class or one of its parents implements Serializable or does something funky in __sleep or __wakeup.